# Sobreescribir el método get_object() en una DetailView

Tags: python, django

En una ListView me aparece una lista de objetos de un típo de modelo.

Para acceder a la DetailView de un objeto específico debo pasarle en la ruta el PK, en el template quedaría algo así:

```
<a href="{% url 'modelo:nombre_ruta' objeto.pk %}">{{ objeto.nombre }}</a>
```

Al hacer click en el enlace la URL quedaría asi:

**dominio.com/modelo/34c2874c-90fc-4153-9827-96980be3d5eb** siendo **34c28...d5eb** el Primary Key de mi modelo.

Mi duda es, dentro de la clase DetailView, cómo puede sobreescribir el método **get_object()** para que en vez de pasarle el PK y hacerlo público, pasarle cualquier otro atributo de mi objeto y rescatarlo de la base de datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La vista `Detail` no necesariamente debes hacerla genérica, lo que sea que vayas a pasar por la URL lo captas en tu vista y lo usas como desees, en este ejemplo se toma la variable `username` que se pasó por la URL:

```py
path('object/< str:username >', myproject.DetailObject, name='detail_object')
```

Luego en la vista se busca el objeto que tenga relación con el usuario utilizando el `username` pasado por contexto

```py
def DetailObjectRequest(request, username):
    requests = MyObject.objects.filter(user__username=username)
    return render(request, template_name='package_details.html', context={'object':requests})
```

espero te sirva.